# Can I use any authentication mechanism on a network server implemented with Java Socket?

Tags: java, sockets, authentication

I implemented a network server with Java ServerSocket and Socket. There's no problem of getting/sending http requests/responses from/to web browsers. However, I want to add authentication ability to the server. I noticed there's such class java.net.Authenticator or java.net.PasswordAuthentication, but I've no idea if I could apply them to the server.

If any of you have used com.sun.httpserver.HttpServer, its authentication is easily supported by com.sun.httpserver.Authenticator which can be set through HttpContext.setAuthenticator() method. Unfortunately, using com.* package may not be allowed in our project. I just want to know if there's any class in java standard packages which can enable me do the same thing as com.sun.httpserver.Authenticator?

I can also implement this by forcing client to provide user and password in http requests, and parse them in the server. But if there's any convenient way, I would be very thankful.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of authentication do you want? HTTP Basic? HTTP Form? NTLM?

Comment: Currently, I think HTTP Basic authentication is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you confuse the [network layers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model).

`com.sun.httpserver.HttpServer` implements the HTTP protocol and works in the application layer. HTTP defines [authentication mechanism](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt), thus `com.sun.httpserver.Authenticator` is an implementation of the *authentication mechanism defined in the HTTP standard*.

`java.net.ServerSocket` and Socket works in the transport layer and implements the TCP protocol. *TCP does not define authentication service.*

When your client-server communication uses HTTP, you should looking for an HTTP server implementation. IMHO isn't a good idea reimplement a HTTP server based on java.net.* package.

Unfortunately Java SE doesn't contains HTTP server -com.sun.httpserver isn't part of the standard-, but there are many open source and portable implementations. The two widely used is [Tomcat](http://www.copperykeenclaws.com/embedding-tomcat-7/) and [Jetty](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Embedding+Jetty).